# Mongodb invalid operator: $eq (version 3.0.6)

Tags: mongodb

In version 3.0.6 of Mongodb (client & server) when I use the operator "$eq" an error appears. Here is an example with the mongo shell:

```
> version()
3.0.6
> db.doc.insert({tags: [ "A", "B", "C" ] })
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.doc.find({tags : {$eq:"A"}})
Error: error: { "$err" : "invalid operator: $eq", "code" : 10068 }
```

What should I do ?

Thanks for helping

Comment: "$eq" was introduced in mongo 3.0. Ideally, it should work. Probably, something to do with the installed Mongo package version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct. Try:

```
db.doc.find({tags: "A"})
```

It is an equivalent way of writing an equality.